# Array to string conversion in PHP : Multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like below. When I echo the values using a for loop, everything looks fine, but I can't use it in order to add data to my database.

```
$title[2][$i];
```

While I can echo it using a for loop, I can't use it as a variable. I think I need to convert it into a variable. I tried a few things using implode but later I found out that it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $site = file_get_contents("URL");
    preg_match_all('@REGEXP@ $site, $title);
    $title[2][$i] = strip_tags($title[2][$i]);
    echo $title[2][$i]; // echoes perfectly fine for x times
}
```

But the query below fails.

```
$sql = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO thing(title) VALUES(?)");
$sql->bind_param("s", $title[2][$i]);
$sql->execute();
```

I think I'll need to use a foreach loop before I execute the query like below, but I got stuck.

```
foreach ($title[2][$i] as $key => $value) {
    $sql4 = "SELECT person_id FROM person where person_name = '$title[2][$i][$key]'";
    $result = $sqli->query($sql4);
    $rowget = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $final = $rowget['person_id'];
}
```

Comment: Can you dump the value of `$title` here?

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(49) { [0]=> string(93) " Title" [1]=> string(93) " Title" [2]=> string(100) " Title2" [3]=> string(100) " Title2" [4]=> string(92) " Title3 " [5]=> string(92) " Title3 " and it goes on like that.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process HTML; use a DOM parser.

Comment: Hello.
You are using `$sql->bind_param("s", $title[2][$i]);`. Do You have `$i` variable initialised in that place?
And one more thing: `$sql4 = "SELECT person_id FROM person where person_name = '$title[2][$i][$key]'";` You should use curly brakets there, as like: `'{$title[2][$i][$key]}'`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    $sql = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO thing(title) VALUES(?)");
    $sql->bind_param("s", (int)$title[2][$i]);
    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: (int) will give `0` here.